# Detect and wake display in OS X Lion

Tags: macos, operating-system, osx-lion

When the display is sleeping in Lion you can no longer wake it by moving the mouse. I need a way to programatically check if the display is sleeping, and if so wake it.

Does anyone know how to do this? In the past I could just generate mouse events and do it, but those don't woke any more with 10.7.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your past code looked like, and it sounds a little hacky, but can you "just generate keyboard events" to do it?